# Duplicate Lines with Python and regex text manipulation

Tags: python, regex

I have many files that I am running multiple regex matches against, and deleting stuff. It's working fine, but whenever there is a match, I get duplicate lines in the bottom that I have delete manually every time. What's going on?

```
for year in range (2004,2009):
    path="/foo/bar/"+str(year)+"/"
    dirs = os.listdir(path)
    for i in range(0,len(dirs)):
        original_file = os.path.join(path, dirs[i])
        f=open(original_file,"r+")
        text=f.read()
        text=re.sub('FY91/92','',text) 
        f.seek(0)
        f.write(text)
        f.close()
```

Comment: Please let this be a lesson: don't assume "bug" unless you have the requisite knowledge to call it one!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about changing to:

```
text=open(original_file).read()
text=re.sub('FY91/92','',text) 
f = open(original_file, 'w')
f.write(text)
f.close()
```

This will overwrite the existing content of the file.

Answer (score 0):

Use `truncate()` method before `close()`